# Is it normal to get 60 confirmations for a transaction in blockchain

Tags: confirmations, copay

Is it normal to get 60 confirmations for a transaction in blockchain and still it is not received and confirmed, can you help I m worrying as this is my first transaction, did I forget anything

Answer (score 4):

Confirmations never stop. Confirmations is simply the number of blocks that have been mined on top of the block that contains your transaction. It will keep incrementing as long as blocks are being mined.

> Is it normal to get 60 confirmations for a transaction in blockchain and still it is not received and confirmed

All wallets I'm aware of show even unconfirmed transactions, and definitely show confirmed transactions with even 1 confirmation. If your wallet is not showing the transaction you are:

1. Connected to a node that is not fully synced for a light wallet.
2. Using a wallet that is attempting to scam you
3. Behind some kind of internet restricting proxy or firewall that prevents a wallet from communicating with nodes
4. Using a Bitcoin full node directly that is not fully synced.

Comment: Many thanks but it already took 7 hours for confirmation, is it normal or I have already lost this amount unfortunately, I ve used copay is it safe, as my status is still pending, what are the steps I need to check, thanks again for big help

Comment: Are you sending or receiving? Copay is a fairly large wallet, and not known to be a scam. They are unlikely to be affected by the points mentioned above. If you look up the txid on an explorer, and it shows confirmed, then the transaction is complete. Try moving your keys to another wallet, such as electrum, and see if it works.